# The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFQUERY

Tags: coldfusion

The query returns only 4-5 rows. It takes less than 1 second to execute. I have trid increasing the timeout of both cfquery and cfsetting but not working. most of the time code runs successfully but i got this error after every 20-30 request. I am using sql server database. I know when you restart the cf server or db server timeout issue occurs sometimes but this error is comming without restarting of any service (cf or sql server). I think there should be some setting changes in cf server please suggest.

The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFQUERY 
The error occurred on line 180.

```
<CFQUERY NAME="Sections" DATASOURCE="abcd">
    SELECT * FROM News_Sections where Section = 'Home' ORDER BY Page_order
</CFQUERY>
```

Comment: The timeout might be related to other activity on either the database or the application server.

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem here is going to be the database *not* ColdFusion. I have a couple of tips for you. First, using the MSSQL Activity Monitor check out blocks (as a wait type). If you see a block or a "head blocker" click on that item and it will show you the query (sometimes :).

[image]

Once you locate it, fixing the problem will involve indexing or changing the query (complex joins or sub-queries often have unexpected consequences).

You might have some luck using "WITH(nolock)"  in the above query to allow for a dirty read (probably ok if you are just getting categories). You might also consider caching the above query using cachedwithin or placing it in the application scope. If it is just broad "home" categories that seems reasonable to me (though obviously I don't know your schema.

My final bit of advice is to examine the page on which the error takes place closely. Sometimes the line number is off a bit. If you have groups of queries together it may not be the query you *think* is erroring out but the one above it. It's not common but it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by Mr. Bracuk, this may not be a problem with your query.  This error has to do with the setting in the CFAdmin for Request timeouts. It is the page that is loading that has experienced the timeout and thrown the error.  When the timeout occurred it just happened to be processing your query.

So, while the query is a good place to start looking, make sure to examine the entire script when searching for the cause of the timeout.